# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data: execute multiple statements in one transaction

Tags: c#, ado.net, enterprise-library

i recently started with an existing project and it works with the Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data objects.

Now i want to execute multiple stored procedures in one transaction (1:n insert which have to all fail or succeed)

But i don't know how....

Can anyone help me out?

Typical code to execute a sp in this project looks like this:

```
Database oDatabase = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase(CONNECTION_STRING_KEY);
DbCommand oDbCommand = oDatabase.GetStoredProcCommand("upCustomer_Insert");

Int32 iCustomerKey = 0;
oDatabase.AddInParameter(oDbCommand, "Firstname", DbType.String, p_oCustomer.FirstName);
oDatabase.AddInParameter(oDbCommand, "Lastname", DbType.String, p_oCustomer.LastName);

oDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(oDbCommand);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make use of a **DbTransaction**:

```
using (DbConnection connection = db.CreateConnection())
{
    connection.Open();
    DbTransaction transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();

    try
    {
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, sp1);
        db.ExecuteNonQuery(transaction, sp2);
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch
    {
        transaction.Rollback();
        throw;
    }
}
```

Notice how the first parameter to **ExecuteNonQuery** is the transaction to use.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748697%28PandP.31%29.aspx).

Comment: by the way, the page in the link shows this: 'Retired Content'. Is this version of the entlib (or the entire entlib?) not supported anymore?

Comment: No problems - let us know how you get on.

Comment: Entlib is still supported, but that particular version (3.1) is outdated. We just shipped version 5.0 last May. The current doc page is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb748697(v=PandP.50).aspx although it's not any different. By the way, I'd strongly recommend using TransactionScope instead of explicit transactions these days. It's just easier to manage and much more composable.

Answer (score 2):

Transaction scope is not thread safe though.  You can not use it for multi-thread applications is what I've read.  This is a real PITA overall.  MS still seems to not understand how to adequately scale software systems.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the calls inside a transactionscope, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx

Comment: Yes, but that's regular ADO.NET - when using Enterprise Library, you should make use of Enterprise Library objects, of which `DbTransaction` is one. Can't believe people still use Enterprise Library BTW.

Comment: Bzzt! Wrong answer! DbTransaction isn't an Entlib object, it's an ADO.NET object. The best approach these days is to use TransactionScope; it's integrated into more parts of the framework, and it's implicit nature means it's much easier. Entlib fully supports TransactionScope as of Entlib 3.